# why map() is mutating original objects in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to create a new array of objects (usersData) using map() in order to add a new property assigned with a value from a secondary array (countries).
During my tests I've noticed that my original array of objects (users) has been modified and the new property (countryName) has been added to it. The same did not happen when I use map to create a new array of objects for my array countries. 
Could someone tell me what is causing this and help me to understand how to avoid such a behaviour?

```
const countries = [
  { id: 3, countryName : "UK" },
  { id: 4, countryName : "Spain" },
  { id: 6, countryName : "Germany"}
];

const users = [
  { id : 1,
    name: "Douglas Camp",
    dateOfBirth: "23-06-1984",
    contactDetails:
      {
        country: 3,
        phone: "7373724997"
      }
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name: "Martin Stein",
    dateOfBirth: "19-08-1992",
    contactDetails:
      {
        country: 6,
        phone: "3334343434"
      }
  },
];

const usersData = users.map(user=> {
  const newUser = {};
  newUser.name = user.name;
  newUser.contactDetails = user.contactDetails;
  newUser.contactDetails.countryName = "UK";
  return newUser;
});

const countriesData = countries.map(country =>
  {
    const newCountry = {};
    newCountry.name = country.countryName;
    newCountry.continent = "Europe";
    return newCountry;
});
console.log(countries);  
console.log(countriesData); 
console.log(users);
console.log(usersData);
```

I expect the elements in the array users to keep its original structure but it has now the property contactDetails.countryName set to "UK"

Comment: you mutate original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration of `users.map()` the `user.contactDetails` holds a reference to an `object` that you are storing in the new `newUser.contactDetails`. So both will refer to the same object on memory. On your particular case, you can solve this spreading the `user.contactDetails` into a new object (like a way of cloning it). But note this will only work for a `1-level` deep object. You should search for `deep-cloning` if your structure is more complicated.

```js
const countries = [{id:3,countryName:"UK"},{id:4,countryName:"Spain"},{id:6,countryName:"Germany"}];

const users = [{id :1,name:"Douglas Camp",dateOfBirth:"23-06-1984",contactDetails:{country:3,phone:"7373724997"}},{id :2,name:"Martin Stein",dateOfBirth:"19-08-1992",contactDetails:{country:6,phone:"3334343434"}},];

const usersData = users.map(user =>
{
    const newUser = {};
    newUser.name = user.name;
    newUser.contactDetails = {...user.contactDetails};
    newUser.contactDetails.countryName = "UK";
    return newUser;
});

const countriesData = countries.map(country =>
{
    const newCountry = {};
    newCountry.name = country.countryName;
    newCountry.continent = "Europe";
    return newCountry;
});

console.log("countries:", countries);  
console.log("countriesData:",countriesData); 
console.log("users:", users);
console.log("usersData:", usersData);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will assume that it only happens to array of nested objects since I did not have the same result when using map() to iterate countries. Am I right?

Comment: It will happen when you copy a reference to a **non-primitive** type in another variable. You can take a read to next link for more info: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 1):

You're building a new array. That doesn't mean you're building a new everything-inside-the-array too.

This:

```
newUser.contactDetails = user.contactDetails;
```

is reusing the `user.contactDetails` object from the original array element, so this:

```
newUser.contactDetails.countryName = "UK";
```

is modifying an object shared between both the new and the old array.

Comment: Good catch; I suggest adding the solution to fix the problem (e.g. using `Object.assign` to clone the object).